# How to make subarrays containing a same string from an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, grouping, sub-array

I have an array like this :

```
[
{
    "title": "name",
    "value": ""
},
{
    "title": "version",
    "value": ""
},
{
    "title": "inventory_name",
    "value": ""
},
{
    "title": "inventory_version",
    "value": ""
},
{
    "title": "differed",
    "value": ""
},
{
    "title": "differed_name",
    "value": ""
},
{
    "title": "accept_error_while_reboot",
    "value": ""
},
{
    "title": "setup_check",
    "value": ""
},
{
    "title": "setup_install",
    "value": ""
},
{
    "title": "setup_install_partial",
    "value": ""
},
{
    "title": "params_install",
    "value": ""
},
{
    "title": "params_install_partial",
    "value": ""
},
{
    "title": "results_install_ok",
    "value": ""
},
{
    "title": "results_install_reboot_defered",
    "value": ""
},
{
    "title": "results_install_reboot_immediate",
    "value": ""
},
{
    "title": "results_install_partial_ok",
    "value": ""
},
{
    "title": "results_install_partial_reboot_defered",
    "value": ""
},
{
    "title": "results_install_partial_reboot_immediate",
    "value": ""
}
];
```

Is it possible to make subarrays that contains the same title field string ?

For example in this case , I will have :

```
array1 = [
 {
  "title": "differed",
  "value": ""
 },
 {
  "title": "differed_name",
  "value": ""
 }
]

array2 = [
 {
  "title": "setup_check",
  "value": ""
 },
 {
  "title": "setup_install",
  "value": ""
 },
 {
  "title": "setup_install_partial",
  "value": ""
 }
]
```

and so on...

In case of single elements , I should have :

```
[
 {
 "title": "name",
 "value": ""
 }
]
```

I'm searching for a generic approach.

I know I can use, for example, `indexOf('results')` with `filter` function, however I'd like if it's possible to avoid the hardcode since it's not always the same titles.

Any ideas ?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t459o6v1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an object to group similar items:

```
var groups = {};

parameter_list.forEach(function(p){ 
   var key = p.title.split('_')[0];
   if(!groups[key]) {
      groups[key] = [];
   }
   groups[key].push(p);
});
```

Working demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/t459o6v1/3/

Comment: Can you explain the `if` statement please ?

Comment: It's creating an empty array if the key doesn't exist (first time it finds a new group).

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a solution using `Immutable.JS`, but you could probably do something similar with `lodash` or `underscore`. Note that this is a functional version, not imperative.

First create a function that gets the prefix:

```
function getPrefix(name) {
    var substr = name.substring(0, name.indexOf('_'))
    return substr ? substr : name;
}
```

Then use the `groupBy` function:

```
Immutable.fromJS(arr).groupBy(element => getPrefix( element['title']))
            .toJS();
```

This will give you an array of arrays with the title as it's key.

Answer (score 1):

Group the data with [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
var groups = data.reduce(function(result, currentValue) {
  var key = currentValue.title.split("_")[0];

  if (typeof result[key] === "undefined") {
    result[key] = [];
  }

  result[key].push(currentValue);

  return result;
}, {});
```

And then (if needed) use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to transform the object into "subarrays"

```js
var subArrays = Object.keys(groups).map(function(key) {
    return groups[key];
});
```

```js
var data = [{
  "title": "name",
  "value": ""
}, {
  "title": "version",
  "value": ""
}, {
  "title": "inventory_name",
  "value": ""
}, {
  "title": "inventory_version",
  "value": ""
}, {
  "title": "differed",
  "value": ""
}, {
  "title": "differed_name",
  "value": ""
}, {
  "title": "accept_error_while_reboot",
  "value": ""
}, {
  "title": "setup_check",
  "value": ""
}, {
  "title": "setup_install",
  "value": ""
}, {
  "title": "setup_install_partial",
  "value": ""
}, {
  "title": "params_install",
  "value": ""
}, {
  "title": "params_install_partial",
  "value": ""
}, {
  "title": "results_install_ok",
  "value": ""
}, {
  "title": "results_install_reboot_defered",
  "value": ""
}, {
  "title": "results_install_reboot_immediate",
  "value": ""
}, {
  "title": "results_install_partial_ok",
  "value": ""
}, {
  "title": "results_install_partial_reboot_defered",
  "value": ""
}, {
  "title": "results_install_partial_reboot_immediate",
  "value": ""
}];


var groups = data.reduce(function(result, currentValue) {
 var key = currentValue.title.split("_")[0];
  
  if (typeof result[key] === "undefined") {
   result[key] = [];
  }
  
  result[key].push(currentValue);
  
  return result;
}, {});


var subArrays = Object.keys(groups).map(function(key) {
 return groups[key];
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(subArrays));
```